RC receiver/transmitter motor control circuit not turning motors
I am trying to make a simple RC Controller/Receiver Motor Control Circuit to eventually to control a tank drive full size mobile robot. It is a intermediary step before I connect my raspberry pi to my motor controller and automate or interface some functions that way.
I'm using:

https://store.ctr-electronics.com/power-distribution-panel/

https://www.andymark.com/products/interstate-sla1116-12v-sla-battery-set-of-2

https://www.andymark.com/products/2-5-in-cim-motor

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cytron.io/p-30amp-7v-35v-smartdrive-dc-motor-driver-2-channels

Flysky FS-iA6B Receiver 2.4Ghz 6 Channel Long Range Dual Pass PPM PWM Output and Telemetry with ibus for RC Car Boat (4PCS) https://a.co/d/d04oIj2

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Htovila-Sticks-Aluminum-Alloy-Telescopic-Poles-Collapsible-Stick-Pole-Adventures-Portable-And-Adjustable/687212018

Some 40 amps breakers. For safety.


Why these specific parts? I do have some experience in First Robotics, so re-using what I know + a new stack more geared at Python or generic programing instead of Java + TalonFX controller combo.
Anyway, what isn't working? Upon booting my setup I can't turn my motors with my RC controller.
What did I try:

In the pic below, I validated I received 12V from source, also upon clicking the MLA or MLB button, I validated that 12 volts is output from the control board.
Not in Pics, I did use the right joystick of my RC controller. I can control the voltage of the 2 motor controller outputs.
I connected the motor directly to my power panel output it turns. No issue.

My guess it's amp issue but not sure?
Any ideas? Any alternative circuit improvements? Would using mosfet work?
Not important but, I am currently testing with 2 motors left and right, but I might just put 4 motors and have them connected in parallel to the 2 motor controller outputs.
Photo of circuit:



The output of the motor controller follows the joystick when unloaded (no motor), but not when a motor is connected (loaded)?

When loaded and unloaded, via the button control or the joystick control, I can measure a 12V output. In all case, the motor is not turning.
The motor works(turning) directly connected to power source with a 40Amp breaker. Don't know what amperage the motor is getting or if motor controller is splitting that in 20 amps for both outputs.

If you measure 12V on the motor connections, but it isn't turning, something isn't connected correctly somewhere. To address you "amps" thought, if there wasn't enough current (amps), then the voltage at the motor would be lower.  But you have 12V, so that isn't the problem.

You were right, I reconnected it and put more pressure on the Anderson connector and it works well! my anderson connector are a bit loose. Thx a lot for the help!!
I see it turning now when I use my RC controller!!!

Glad it worked out!
